# Rolling_mean over a certain time period with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

**TL;DR : is there a solution for:**

- adding data in realtime to a DataFrame (with a *non-constant* sample rate: sometimes 1 second, sometimes 0.2 seconds, sometimes 2 seconds, etc.  between each new data)
- being able to compute a `rolling_mean` on a fixed-5-seconds window (regardless if there are 10 or 100 or only 2 samples in this window)

---

More precisely:

```
import pandas as pd, time
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['x'])

for i in range(10):
    df.ix[pd.datetime.now()] = {'x': 10 + i}
    time.sleep(0.2)         # here 0.2 seconds between each new data...

df.ix[pd.datetime.now()] = {'x': 20}
time.sleep(1)               # here 1 second...
df.ix[pd.datetime.now()] = {'x': 21}
time.sleep(3)               # here 3 seconds...
df.ix[pd.datetime.now()] = {'x': 22}
```

gives this for `df`:

```
                          x
2016-01-08 13:57:10.679  10
2016-01-08 13:57:10.882  11
2016-01-08 13:57:11.085  12
2016-01-08 13:57:11.287  13
2016-01-08 13:57:11.489  14
2016-01-08 13:57:11.691  15
2016-01-08 13:57:11.893  16
2016-01-08 13:57:12.095  17
2016-01-08 13:57:12.297  18
2016-01-08 13:57:12.499  19
2016-01-08 13:57:12.701  20
2016-01-08 13:57:13.703  21
2016-01-08 13:57:16.706  22
```

and this for `pd.rolling_mean(df, 5)`

```
                          x
2016-01-08 13:57:10.679 NaN
2016-01-08 13:57:10.882 NaN
2016-01-08 13:57:11.085 NaN
2016-01-08 13:57:11.287 NaN
2016-01-08 13:57:11.489  12
2016-01-08 13:57:11.691  13
2016-01-08 13:57:11.893  14
2016-01-08 13:57:12.095  15
2016-01-08 13:57:12.297  16
2016-01-08 13:57:12.499  17
2016-01-08 13:57:12.701  18
2016-01-08 13:57:13.703  19
2016-01-08 13:57:16.706  20
```

Of course `pd.rolling_mean(df, 5)` computes the rolling mean over a period of 5 rows, which is not what I want : **I would like a period of 5 seconds instead**.

One solution would be to `df.resample('1S', ...)` but as I want to compute a new `rolling_mean` each time new data has been added, **that means that I should `.resample(...)` the whole DataFrame many time per minutes, this is really very time-consuming, and I think it's not a clean solution.** (in my real use case, the DataFrame is big).

**What's a clean solution for this?**

Comment: Did you find a solution that worked without consuming a lot of time?

Answer (score 1):

What about storing the rolling mean in your df when you add the new datum?

```
import datetime as dt
latest = pd.datetime.now()
five_secs = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)
new_x=99
df.ix[latest] = {'x':new_x,
                 'five_second_mean':df[df.index > latest - five_secs].x.append(pd.Series(new_x).mean()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [series apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) function to capture last 5 seconds of specific row. With this approach, you can run it once when all data is complete. Only caveat with your setup is you cannot use `apply()` on an index, so use a temporary timestamp column (equal to index value):

```
import datetime
...

# SERIES MEAN FUNCTION
def runMean(row):
    ser = df.x[(df['timeval'] > row - datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)) &
               (df['timeval'] <= row)]
    return ser.mean()

# APPLY FUNCTION
df['timeval'] = df.index
df['last5secMean'] = df['timeval'].apply(runMean)

df = df[['x','last5secMean']]
```